# Plotting list using matplot lib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a list like  :
   [[5, 1.1066720079718957], [10, 1.075297753414681], [15, 1.0958222358382397], [20, 1.092081009894558], [25, 1.0968130408510393]]

I am trying to plot using matplotlib 
where values 5,10,15,20,25 are on  x-axis where as 1.1066720079718957,1.075297753414681,1.0958222358382397,1.092081009894558,1.0968130408510393 on  y-axis

I am not able to do it in few lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [[5, 1.1066720079718957], [10, 1.075297753414681], [15, 1.0958222358382397], [20, 1.092081009894558], [25, 1.0968130408510393]]

plt.plot([i[0] for i in data], [i[1] for i in data])
plt.show()
```

Maybe these two links will also useful if you are working with nested lists and list comprehensions

1. [Nested lists python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189169/nested-lists-python)
2. [What does "list comprehension" mean? How does it work and how can I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it)