# Can someone explain what the mylist[a][b] does in this Python code?

Tags: python

```
mylist = [ [2,4,1], [1,2,3], [2,3,5] ]
a=0
b=0
total = 0
while a <= 2:
    while b < 2:
        total += mylist[a][b]
        b += 1
    a += 1
    b = 0 
print (total)
```

I don't understand what `mylist[a][b]` does.

I tried adding print statements and checked each of the outputs, but I still can't figure out what it does.

The output with print statement I got was:
(each printed output every time it goes through the loop:)

```
2
4
1
2
2
3
(total)
14
```

I thought each output were the items inside the lists in `mylist`, but realized it's not. I also tried changing the numbers inside the lists, I still don't understand. Can someone simply explain it to me please?

Comment: `mylist[a]` will be one of the 3 sublists in `mylist`, and `mylist[a][b]` will be one of the 3 numbers inside that sublist. Is that what you want to know?

Comment: Look at it as a matrix. `Mylist[0]` is your first array which is [2,4,1] here mylist[0][0]  is 2,mylist[0,1] is 4 and  mylist[0,2] is 1 from [2,4,1].

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes, oh god I feel so embarrassed with getting confused with it thank you so much, thanks also for editing my question

Comment: I'm voting to close as duplicate of [Nested lists python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189169/nested-lists-python)

Answer (score 1):

The object between the [ and ] brackets is a "list" and a list can be made of other lists.

When you want to get the value from a list at a particular position, you use the `[n]` notation, where the `n` is the position (starting at zero).

If the object at position `n` is also a list, then you can extract items from that sub-list by again using the square brackets.

So, if I have a list `l = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ]` then `l[0]` is equal to `[1,2,3]` and therefore `l[0][1]` is equal to 2.

The code you posted is looping over the lists inside the list and then the items inside each of those inner lists.

Comment: thank you so much for such simple and complete explanation, I already know the answer to my question even before I get to read your example because of your explanations, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, You can visualise this code `mylist[a][b]` as `(mylist[a])[b]`. So 1st part will get a value of position `[a]` from my list and then it will get a value of position `[b]` of `mylist[a]`. For an example:

```
mylist = [ [2,4,1], [1,2,3], [2,3,5] ]
```

Let's say `a=1` , `b=0`
If you want to print `mylist[a][b]`. It will 1st get [1, 2, 3] then it will get the value at 0 position of the list. So the final output should be `1`