# indexes in a list

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [comparing lists python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184768/comparing-lists-python)

I have 1 original list such as:

```
original = [1, 2, 3]
```

and another list with nested lists (with the same size) such as:

```
bigList = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2], [3, 2, 3]...]
```

and I want to count how many indexes in each nested list is the same as in the original list.
this is what i wrote:

```
count= 0
for innerlist in (bigList):
    for indexes in (innerlist):
        for i in (original):
            if indexes == i:
            count= count+1
```

The problem is that it will count all the correct places in all the nested lists together, but I want it to count how many correct places are in each nested list.
how should I do it?

Comment: Please stop posting the same question over and over again! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184768/comparing-lists-python/8184949#8184949

Comment: The simplest way to get the number of elements in a list is to use `len(innerlist)`, rather than to count them.

Answer (score 1):

You did ask this question in the past and my answer was as follows:

---

You can do it like this:

```
from itertools import izip
def matches(input_lists, base_list):
    for l in input_lists:
        yield sum(1 for a, b in izip(l, base_list) if a==b)
```

and the result will be following:

```
>>> for i in matches([[1,2,3],[2,3,1],[0,2,0]], [1,2,4]):
    i


2
0
1
```

which works as expected.

The [`izip()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) is generator function, which is better
solution than [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip). Also `matches()` we defined is generator
function, so there should be less problems when processing large
lists.

Did it help? Is it clean enough?

**EDIT:**

If you **can't import** anything, just replace `izip()` with built-in `zip()`:

```
def matches(input_lists, base_list):
    for l in input_lists:
        yield sum(1 for a, b in zip(l, base_list) if a==b)
```

How does it work now?

Comment: isn't it a little bit complicated for what it really is?

Comment: @julio.alegria: I do not think so, but I may be wrong. Please clarify. The original question was afair about big lists, thus the iterator. My solution has only 3 lines (not including import statement), employs iterator for robustness and is quite reusable, so I tend to think it is not too complex. If you give me alternative solution, I will answer. Yours solution does not answer the question, though.

Comment: Well it does work but I cant import anything it should be much more basic then that.

Comment: I also think you can solve it without importing stuff, check my solution below

Comment: @user1040563: You have said for the first time about this additional requirement. It is very simple to fix - you just use standard `zip()` function instead of more advanced and more robust `izip()`. Does it work for you now?

Comment: @julio.alegria: Of course you can, but `izip()` is better suited for some cases, thus I used it. I now replaced it with `zip()` and my solution is 3-lines long (yours is 6-line long now).

Comment: `complexity != number of lines`. I just said that if I were a newbie in Python, I would get kinda scared with your solution (`zip`, `yield`)

Comment: @julio.alegria: `complexity != number of unknown functions` :) In my solutions both `zip` and `yield` decrease the complexity of the algorithm - the first one replaces the need for getting elements separately by index (as in your solution), the second helps in not storing full list of results in the memory (again, as in your solution). But indeed there may be some concepts a newbie may have problems to get familiar with, but I think this is rather `yield` than `zip` (which is rather easy if you read the docs).

Comment: I agree with you in everything you just said

Answer (score 1):

Here is a posible solution:

```
matches = []
for mylist in bigList:
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, len(mylist)):
        count += int(mylist[i] == original[i])
    matches.append(count)
```

**EDIT:** Worked perfectly on my computer:

```
>>> original = [1, 2, 3]
>>> bigList = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2], [3, 2, 3]]
>>> matches = []
>>> for mylist in bigList:
...     count = 0
...     for i in range(0, len(mylist)):
...         count += int(mylist[i] == original[i])
...     matches.append(count)
... 
>>> matches
[3, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Your solution counts **all** the matches from nested lists, but OP said **he already did that** and said exactly: " _...but I want it to count how many correct places are in each nested list_ ".

Comment: you're right, I didn't quite understood the answer, edited!

Comment: its still doesn't work. if i print the matches it shows me: 
[1] 
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3] 
[1, 2, 3, 0]
 [1, 2, 3, 0, 1]
 [1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1]
 [1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0]
 [1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
 [1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2]

 instead of just [3, 1, 2]

Comment: are you sure you implemented it right? (indentation and all?). This code is just appending `count` for each element of biglist, that result is imposible!

Comment: yeah its printing:
'[1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2]'
9 indexes, 3 for each nested list instead of just 1 for each.
its checking and counting after each index in the nested lists instead of just counting when it finishes with each list

Comment: @julio.alegria: It may not be a good idea to **overwrite quite common and useful keyword `list`** in your code. Actually I think it is extremely bad idea.

Comment: yes, you're indeed right @Tadeck. I shouldn't have done that. user1040563, I still don't know what's wrong, I'm getting the right answer on my computer

Comment: @julio.alegria: The problem with `list` overwritten is that you are unable to convert into list anything after (and during) the loop. Please change that into something less conflicting. When it comes to @user1040563's problems in implementing your solution, I believe he is indenting `matches.append(count)` too much by one level :)

Comment: Yep, I also think that's the problem. About the overwritten function, as I said before, you're totally right, but in this case in particular doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @julio.alegria: I tend to disagree about that - `list` will be overwritten everywhere after the `for` loop, so you do not even know how it will influence OP's script (because you do not know the whole script). But I would like to barter with you - if you change the name `list` into some non-conflicting one, I will upvote your answer :) I promise.

Comment: I changed it because it's always good to have more reputation (haha). But just so you know, after the `for` statement, the `list` variable is free again! (so it's the Python built-in function again). Try it!

Comment: @julio.alegria: The point is that it is not free :) Did you try it? If not, just go to this link: http://codepad.org/QyJxaUmu and you will see that after the `for` loop, `list` is equal to the last element of the iterated variable. So, in your case, calling `list()` (eg. to convert something into list, or to create empty list) would throw: `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`. Am I right or am I not? Anyways, promised upvoted has been made.

Comment: damn! you're right. I don't know why I thought this would work.